# How to use a sub-form in Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am working on a project that will have a lot of query forms.
There are a number of field "collections" that will be used on multiple forms. 
I would like to use sub-forms for this but I have, as yet, been unable to get this to work.

I consistently get this exception:

> The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class SiteBundle\Entity\EntityB. `You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "SiteBundle\Entity\EntityB"` or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class SiteBundle\Entity\EntityB to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.

I have isolated the problem into an example that is much simpler than my actual application and present the source for the example here. The example is where the EntityB class comes from.

My sub-form has a choice field in it and if I comment that field out, the exception goes away so I'm guessing it has something to do with that.

**The Entity Behind the Main Form:**

```
// src/SiteBundle/Entity/EntityA.php

namespace SiteBundle\Entity;

class EntityA
{
  private $customerCode;
  private $customerName;
  private $b; // (an instance of EntityB)

  public function getCustomerCode()
  {
    return $this->customerCode;
  }

  public function setCustomerCode( $customerCode )
  {
    $this->customerCode = $customerCode;
    return $this;
  }

  public function getCustomerName()
  {
    return $this->customerName;
  }

  public function setCustomerName( $customerName )
  {
    $this->customerName = $customerName;
    return $this;
  }

  public function getB()
  {
    return $this->b;
  }

  public function setB( $b )
  {
    $this->b = $b;
    return $this;
  }
}
```

**The Main Form**

```
// src/SiteBundle/Form/Type/FormA.php

namespace SiteBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FormA extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
  {
    $builder
      ->add( 'customerCode', 'text', [ 'label' => 'Customer code:', ] )
      ->add( 'customerName', 'text', [ 'label' => 'Customer name:' ] )
      ->add( 'b', 'FormB', [ 'label' => 'Option:' ] );
  }


  public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver )
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults( [ 'data_class' => 'SiteBundle\Entity\EntityA' ] );
  } // configureOptions()


  public function getName()
  {
    return 'FormA';
  } // getName()
}
```

**The Entity Behind the Sub-Form**

```
// src/SiteBundle/Entity/entityB.php

namespace SiteBundle\Entity;    

class EntityB
{
  private $opt1 = false;
  private $opt2 = false;
  private $opt3 = false;
  private $start;
  private $end;

  public function getOption()
  {
    return $this;
  }

  public function setOption( $val )
  {
    switch( $val )
    {
      case 1:
        $this->opt1 = true;
        $this->opt2 = false;
        $this->opt3 = false;
        break;

      case 2:
        $this->opt2 = true;
        $this->opt1 = false;
        $this->opt3 = false;
        break;

      case 3:
        $this->opt3 = true;
        $this->opt1 = false;
        $this->opt2 = false;
        break;
    }
    return $this;
  }

  public function getStart()
  {
    return $this->start;
  }

  public function setStart( $start )
  {
    $this->start = $start;
    return $this;
  }

  public function getEnd()
  {
    return $this->end;
  }

  public function setEnd( \DateTime $end )
  {
    $this->end = $end;
    return $this;
  }
}
```

**The Sub-Form**

```
// src/SiteBundle/Form/Type/FormB.php

namespace SiteBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FormB extends AbstractType
{
  public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
  {
    $builder
      ->add( 'option',
             'choice',
             [
               'expanded' => true,
               'multiple' => false,
               'label'    => 'Option:',
               'choices'  =>
                 [
                   '1'  => 'One',
                   '2'  => 'Two',
                   '3'  => 'Three'
                 ],
               'attr' => [ 'class' => 'checkbox-inline' ],
             ] )
      ->add( 'start',
             'date',
             [
               'label' => 'Start date:',
               'widget' => 'single_text',
             ] )
      ->add( 'end',
             'date',
             [
               'label' => 'End date:',
               'widget' => 'single_text',
             ] );
  }

  public function ConfigureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver )
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults( [ 'data_class' => 'SiteBundle\Entity\EntityB' ] );
  }

  public function getName()
  {
    return 'FormB';
  }
}
```

**Entries in services.yml**

```
 # src/SiteBundle/Resources/config/service.yml

 form.a:
    class:  SiteBundle\Form\Type\FormA
    tags:
      - { name: form.type, alias: FormA }

  form.b:
    class:  SiteBundle\Form\Type\FormB
    tags:
      - { name: form.type, alias: FormB }
```

**The Controller Action Method**

```
  /**
   * @route( "/debug", name="debug" )
   */
  public function debugAction( Request $request )
  {
    $b = new EntityB();
    $b->setOption( 1 )
      ->setStart( new \DateTime( 'today' ))
      ->setEnd( new \DateTime( 'today + 7 days' ));

    $a = new EntityA();
    $a->setCustomerCode( '1234' )
      ->setCustomerName( 'Test Customer' )
      ->setB( $b );

    $form = $this->createForm( 'FormA', $a );
    $form->handleRequest( $request );
    if( $form->isValid() )
    {
      $this->getFlashbag()->add( 'info', "Form successfully validated" );
    }

    $vars =
      [
        'form' => $form->createView()
      ];
    return $this->render( 'SiteBundle:debug:form.html.twig', $vars );

  } // debugAction()
```

I am setting the data_class parameter in `EntityB::ConfigureOptions()` which makes the highlighted portion of the exception message above that much more confusing.

I suspect that I am missing something fairly basic here but don't know what.

**Environment:**
- PHP 5.5.9
- Symfony 2.7.3
I ran `composer self-update` and `composer update` today to be sure that I'm current.

Comment: The formb expects that entity b has a property called option.  EntityB::getOption is returning $this which explains the error.  Adjust getOption to return an actual scaler value.

Comment: Modified EntityB::getOption() to return 1. No joy. Exact same exception. Rats.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm guessing your entities and types are not really called A and B?  The code you posted is not your actual code?  Check carefully.  I verified your exception and the cure.  You might not be editing the code you think your are.  Post a link to your github repo if you still have issues so we can see the exact code without edits.

Comment: The code that I have posted generates the exact (word-for-word) exception that I posted. Try this code for yourself.

Comment: I did copy/paste/test your posted code before my previous comment.  That's why I was guessing that maybe there was a mismatch.  It happens more often than you might think.  You are in development mode?  I suppose you could try clearing the cache but you should not need to in development mode.  All I can suggest at this point is to create a brand new project, add the entities and test without anything else going on.

Comment: Yes, I am in development mode. Have deleted the cache/dev directory. The example code that I posted here is real code that I developed specifically to demonstrate the problem. I copied it pasted it into my question.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that @Cerad's first comment was correct.

> The formb expects that entity b has a property called option. EntityB::getOption is returning $this which explains the error. Adjust getOption to return an actual scaler value.

I have no idea why my initial test of that failed, but later testing was successful.

I must say that the wording of the exception is quite misleading and confusing.